# Pointer pre and post increment in c language?

Tags: c, pointers

So, i am a student still learning about programming. As i was learning i came across a pointer program that had pre and post increment. When i executed the program i was a bit confused.

**Code**

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int a=20;
    int *p;
    p =&a;
    printf("%d\n %d\n %u\n",a,*p,p);
    *p++;
    printf("%d\n %d\n %u\n",a,*p,p);
    p =&a;
    ++*p;
    printf("%d\n %d\n %u\n",a,*p,p);
}
```

**Output**

```
20
20
146459356

20
146459360 /* this output */
146459360

21
21
146459356 /* and this */
```

So, how did the ***p** after post increment display a garbage value and why did **p** show address of **a** after pre increment? Or is there any fault of the compiler? I use Ubuntu 16.04.
Detailed answer would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: `Dereferencing an allocated memory invokes undefined behavior.` Very interesting and I would even say a revolutionary theory. @haccks

Comment: @PeterJ; OK. It should be **unallocated**.

Comment: 1. Dereferencing an unallocated memory invokes undefined behavior. In your program after `*p++;` dereferencing `p` will invoke this behavior. 2. Using wrong format specification for a data type also results in UB. Correct format for pointer data type is `%p`. 3. Signature of main should be `int main(void)`.

Comment: ... and `#include`s are a necessary part of **any** [mcve]. But the main question of yours is perfectly addressed in the duplicate target.